# How to specify tensorboard projector embedding colors

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using tensorflow's (1.14) tensorboard projector plugin, embedding trained data with labeled classes. I'd like to be able to specify the colors tensorboard choses to display.

I've looked through the source code but have had trouble locating where the color values are specified.

Here are some relevant snippets of my code:

```py
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
...
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver(tf_data)
    sess.run(initializers)
    saver.save(sess, '.')
    config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
    embedding = config.embeddings.add()
    embedding.metadata_path = 'labels.tsv'
    projector.visualize_embeddings(tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter('.'), config)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/61

In short, you need a metadata.tsv file with a column for coloring